# Changing Alpha of UITableView Section on Cell Select

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have an issue when using multiple table view sections. I am trying to change the alpha for a cell when the user taps it. Each section in the table view has one row.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  NSIndexPath *indexPathInSection = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0  inSection:indexPath.section];
  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathInSection].contentView.alpha = 0.2f;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  NSIndexPath *indexPathInSection = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section];
  [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathInSection].contentView.alpha = 1.0f;
} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   MatchCell *cell = (MatchCell *)[self cellForIdentifier:tableView:@"MatchCell"];
   MatchedUser *user = (MatchedUser *)(self.matches)[indexPath.section];

  [self configureMatchCell:cell :user :tableView];

  NSIndexPath *selection = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section];
  if (selection.section == indexPath.section && cell.isSelected){
    cell.contentView.alpha = 0.2f;
  }else{
    cell.contentView.alpha = 1.0f;
  }
  return cell;
}
```

The alpha is applied to the cell that is tapped but other cells are also changed. This is because it is applied according to the row number not the section and row number. How can I specify the cell at the section and row index only?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're being overly specific about the indexPath you want to change the alpha on, if each section really has only 1 row. Have you tried just passing indexPath into your calls to `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Also, what does `-configureMatchCell` do? Can you share the code?

Comment: Is `cell.isSelected` ever getting set back to `NO`? I bet that your condition in that if statement is never making it into the `else` path.

Comment: Yes you are right. I need to have a look at this more but your comment has pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.